# Java string split using multiple operator delimiter

Tags: java, split, delimiter

I need to divide a string into two parts at the first occurrence of any one of these operators:

||, &&, ==, !=, <, >, <=, >=, +, -, *, /, and %.

I think `string.split()` might be my best option, but I'm not certain. My problem is that I don't know exactly how to incorporate all of those symbols into a delimiter string for split(), or if that's even possible.

So, my question is, how would I create a delimiter string containing all of those operators? And if that's not possible, what would be the best alternative approach? Thanks!

Comment: Read the javadoc of `split` then look into regular expressions.

Comment: `split` is most useful when a string could contain multiple occurrences of the same delimiter pattern.  If you're just looking for one occurrence and breaking the string into two parts, it might be easier and a bit more flexible to use [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [`Matcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html).  You'll have to learn about regular expressions either way.

Comment: so if the string is `aa+bb==cc||dd-xx!=ff` you want two strings: `a` and `bb==cc||dd-xx!=ff`?

Comment: @deanosaur yes, essentially. The second part is going to be run through another method, which will run it through this method again to determine if it has any of the operators.

Comment: perhaps you want `StringTokenizer`?

Answer (score 1):

So this litte program demonstrates how to do this:

```
public class RegexpSplitter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splitString("56&&78&&13")));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splitString("ab==cd")));
    }

    public static String[] splitString(String str) {
        return str.split("\\|\\||&&|==|!=|<|>|<=|>=|\\+|-|\\*|/|%", 2);
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
[56, 78&&13]
[ab, cd]
```

Here is the javadoc of `String.split`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29.

There are two implementations. The one I use, allows to specify a `limit` on how large the result array may be. So on the first occurance of one of your "control" characters the String is split and given back.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed, I just couldn't figure out how to get all of those operators in there in the correct syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
myString.split("(\\|\\|)|(&&)|(==)|(!=)|(<=)|(>=)|[\\+\\*/%<>]");
```

I think that should do it - although that will split on all occurrences, not just the first one...

Comment: Thanks, but the first two characters in the parentheses `'(` give me an "invalid character constant" error.

Comment: Sorry - stupid mistake on my part - Java strings are quote delimited. Fixed now.

Comment: Also forgot to double escape the back slashes - serves me right for trying to answer in a hurry - but I see you've got a better answer now anyway.